# jquery hide div isn't working upon success call back

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I was hoping someone can point out why my div (in my case, I use li) isn't hiding using jquery upon successful execution of my php script.

Here is my query code (from jquery impromptu plugin):

```
if(v){
    var bid = f.bannerid;
    $.post('/manage/<?=CFILE?>',{bannerid:f.bannerid,action:'deleteBanner',cid:<?=$contentid?>,uid:'<?=$_SESSION['userid']?>'},{callback:function(data){
        if(data=='true'){
            $('#list_'+bid).hide('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });                                  
        }else{ 
            $.prompt('An Error Occured while removing this banner'); 
        }                           
    }});
}
```

here is part of my html code:

```
<li id="list_47">
<div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="title id="bannerid59"><img src="banner_45_10.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="action"><a href="javascript:;" title="Delete Banner" class="deleteBanner" onclick="deleteBanner(59);">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-right">
        <span class="small">Sort Order: 2</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
<li id="list_48">
<div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="title id="bannerid60"><img src="banner_45_11.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="action"><a href="javascript:;" title="Delete Banner" class="deleteBanner" onclick="deleteBanner(60);">Delete</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-right">
        <span class="small">Sort Order: 3</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Finally, here is my simple php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="deleteBanner"){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM banner where banner_image='".$_POST['bid']."' AND users_id='".$_POST['uid']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    print "true";
    exit;
}
```

I am able to delete my banner from mySQL database without any problem using these codes but i can't seem to hide the deleted li (for example, list_47) upon script execution.

Any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Could you try this? $('#list_'+bid).hide('slow').remove(); It probably remove the element without fade effect, but it worth trying.

Comment: hi StrouMfios, I tried that and it's still the same and not removing the li on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) correctly, your `{callback: function() ... }` is supposed to be just the function:

```
$.post(
    '/manage/<?=CFILE?>',
    {bannerid:f.bannerid,action:'deleteBanner',cid:<?=$contentid?>,uid:'<?=$_SESSION['userid']?>'},
    function(data) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

`$.post` will look for a function in its argument list but won't find one; since there is no callback function passed, no callback will be called and your `<div>` won't be hidden.

Compare these two:

- [Pass a function and it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Mhy64/)
- [Pass `{callback:function() {/*...*/} }` and it doesn't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hybkz/)

Comment: hi mu is too short, you are 100% right on this, once I removed the callback function from the code, it works...thanks for catching that.